# How to read DECIMAL datatype in solr schema.xml : audit_internal_id decimal(38,10)

Tags: solr

I am using Solr 4.10.3
I am having below datatypes in my hive table:

audit_internal_id             | decimal(38,10)
alert_id                      | decimal(38,10)

This Hive table stores data in parquet file format.
For indexing in solr, I need to read parquet files using Morphlines.
But I am not sure, how to deal with decimals in solr schema.xml.
Please suggest.

Comment: What are you going to use the values for?

Comment: Want to index,store and search them

Comment: _How_ are you going to search them? Exact matches? Ranges? Will the ids really have decimals attached?

Comment: I will match as exact matches,No ranges. Id's don't have a decimal attached. but their data type is DECIMAL(38,10). And I do not have a choice to change the datatype in parquet files.

Comment: sample data:
--------------+------------------------------+--+
| alert_audits.audit_internal_id  | alert_audits.alert_id  | alert_audits.created_date  | alert_audits.event  |
+---------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------+
| 55262                           | 39428                  | 2018-02-14                 | NOTE_ADDED          |

Comment: sample table structure

|           col_name            |                     data_type                      |        comment        |
| # col_name                    | data_type                                          | comment               |
|                               | NULL                                               | NULL                  |
| audit_internal_id             | decimal(38,10)                                     |                       |
| alert_id                      | decimal(38,10)

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want direct matches, and you don't have any decimals, and it's a growing ID, you can safely map it to a `LongPointField`. You can get exact matches, as well as range queries later if necessary.

If it's not a regular, increasing integer (meaning that the value might not map inside the 64 bits of a regular long), use a `string` field. It'll only give you exact matches, but that's what you need.

When adding a decimal value to a long field, the reminder decimals will be removed. For a string field, you will want to attach a [PatternReplaceCharFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/charfilterfactories.html) that removes everything behind the dot.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/137650/matslindh
Can you please let me know, if I am having 200 hive tables and want to index and do a solr search on these tables data then how to configure it in single schema.xml file?
Is there any other way to deal with this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Hive. If you want to index multiple sources with different fields into a single core / collection, usually you create a schema that fits all the sources.